# why simple select query returns List<Mymodel> but join query return List<Object> in jpa

Tags: java, exception, jpa, model-view-controller, playframework

I am using play framework with jpa. I have a model Jobads with 2 functions to findall() findByLocation()

**My Model**

```
  public class Jobads {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;


        private String title;

        @ManyToOne
        private Jobindistry industry;


        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(
                name = "jobads_city",
                joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "jobads_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "city_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
        private List<City> city;
    }
```

**findall()**

```
 public static List<Jobads> findall() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Jobads> el = JPA.em().createQuery("from Jobads order by id").getResultList();
            return el;
        }
```

**findByLocation()**

```
public static List<Jobads> findByLocation(String location) {
  List<Jobads> jadList = JPA.em().createQuery("FROM Jobads j join j.city c WHERE  c.name LIKE :location  ").setParameter("location", "%" + location + "%").getResultList();

return jadList;

}
```

I am printing both the function output in my console findall() works fine but findByLocation() gives me an exception **[ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to models.Jobads]**

Why this problem in occuring only in findByLocation() and what is the solution of this problem??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because that's how HQL queries without a select clause work. Note that these are not valid JPQL queries. JPQL makes the select clause mandatory, and using a select clause would allow you to specify what you want the query to return:

```
select j from Jobads j join j.city c WHERE c.name LIKE :location
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about what is returned by your second query : you will have a table with two rows due to the `join` statement. However, I don't really know what will be the type of the output in this case, try using `getClass` on it to see.

Answer (score 1):

`createQuery()` method accepts two parameters, query and the type of the query result, thus you can write type safe query this way:

`createQuery("FROM Jobads j join j.city c WHERE  c.name LIKE :location", Jobads.class);`